# Domain to Workgroup

Tags: windows

I have a few pcs that I need to remove from Sasha Mosley's Domain Server. They don't need to connect to it anymore as they use an online service now.

Only two older PCs will continue to login to that old 2003 server.

How can I remove the PCs from the Domain without losing any data (docs, emails) I don't think they use exchange.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in addtion to tsc_chazz answer

myelf prefere commands to show examples:

Start `CMD`as administrator on the affected machine
for english installations, usually the administrator group is called "administrators" you may need to use the localized version of it.

### Part 1

```
rem change to what it shall be
LOCUSR=localuser
LOCADM=localadm
ADMGROUP=administrators

rem No change usually needed here, run aslong it is been joined
net user $LOCUSR /add * 
net user $LOCADM /add *
net group %ADMGROUP $LOCADM /add
runas /U:.\$LOCUSR "cmd /c echo profile created, so we neeed not to login"
runas /U:.\$LOCADM "cmd /c echo profile created, so we neeed not to login"
```

Greg greatly suggested that you check that you have your BitLocker Recovery-Key. run the following to obtain it (and print it out!):

```
manage-bde -protectors -get C:
```

While C: must be repeated for every drive that is bitlocker enabled

Additonally, you should enable the local administrator account and set a password, or leave it disabled and use the above new one created.

### Part 2

We need to copy the files, you may also just move it depends on your choice.
I usually used to migrate robocopy due it has Multithread support and could be run again

```
robocopy C:\users\domuser\ C:\users\localuser\ /a /z /v /mt:32
```

### Part 3

#### Keep the System still joined to the domain!

Login as Local User, start the Outlook and connect IMAP or Exchange.
If POP(3) has been used, it's a bad situation, but you can export manually the old Data file as an archive and import it again in the new Profile.

Furthermore, test the usual applications by simply running them once.

### Part 4

#### Leave the domain

Verify from above, that you have created and tested the local admin, that you created. Because otherwise you would have to hack your computer to reset the password, which is not an ideal solution. ;) (But ultimatebootcd is a friend of you)
Reboot and test again with the new created local user.

### Part 5

#### Verification and Clean up

In that point, that you created the user and have verified the Device, its a good way to clean up \users folder. Specially if the Localuser will have local admin rights. Reminder on the Data protection.

Also maybe a look into the root folder for cleanup is also mostly a good idea.

Dont forget, to delete the old Device out of the Active Directory.
And if you want to be sure, make a backup of the files before deletion.

thats usually the way i do, for unsupported devices in the past to be moderately inline with the IT-Rules of the department.

Comment: On part one, I would phrase it enable the administrator account/verify credentials/password, and also get the Bitlocker recovery password if applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Docs and emails are stored in the profile of the domain user. When you leave the domain, those documents may stay with the PC or they may be erased depending on domain policy.

What you need to do is create two new local users on each PC that you need to migrate out; make one administrator-level, one user-level. As domain user, grant the local user permission to access all your files. Log out and back in as local user; copy all the domain user's files into the local users' space. You can then log in as domain admin and remove the computer from the domain. Logging in as the local user will give you back the documents. The local administrator should be able to grant permissions to any files that get forgotten or lost in the shuffle, if your policies don't erase them when you leave the domain.

Email can be trickier. If you are not using Exchange, likely you are using IMAP. If so, the emails are all on the mail server, and are identified by a (probably) non-domain user ID and password; set up your mail client to use that ID and password and you should get all your mail back. If you are using Exchange, you'll have to keep using your domain ID and password to retain access to your mailbox.